# Statistically significant deviation from expected probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a list of items of length $l$. Each item is one of a large number of possible discrete values each with it's own probability of occurring. Given the expected probably of an item having the value $x$ is $p$, how many instances of value $x$ in the list would represent a statistically significant deviation from the expected probability? (i.e. the hypothesis that value $x$ has a probability of $p$ is incorrect).

To be more precise (if it makes things simpler), I'm interested in the case where the expected probability is too low.

I'm not a mathematician so a name / explanation for any techniques used would be helpful, so that I can go off and educate myself and/or post more questions here.

Comment: Welcome to SE! See my answer below. Let me know if you need more details. Don't forget to accept the anwser if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface.** Your problem can be solved via a *concentration of measure* argument for a binomial random variable.

---

Say your list contains $N$ items, where $N = l$ in your original notation (one notation is not as good as another). Let $\widehat{N}=\widehat{N}(x)$ be the number of times the item $x$ occurs in your list. Then $\widehat{N} = \sum_{i=1}^NB_i$, where $B_1,\ldots,B_N$ are iid Bernoulli random variables with mean $p=p(x)$. Thus $\widehat{N}$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $N$ and $p$ respectively.

## Simple case: $p$ is close to $1/2$

By [Hoeffding's inequality](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_de_Hoeffding#Cas_de_la_loi_binomiale), we have the **nonasymptotic** tail-bound
$$
\mathbb P(|\widehat{N}-Np| > t\sqrt{N}) \le 2\exp(-2t^2),\;\forall t > 0.
\tag{1}
$$

Let $100(1-\alpha)\%$ be your level of confidence, so that you want $\mathbb P(|\widehat{N}-Np| > t\sqrt{N}) \le \alpha$. By (1), it suffices to set $\alpha = 2\exp(-2t^2)$ and get  $t = \sqrt{\dfrac{\log(2/\alpha)}{2}}$. This gives the following rule:

> *If $\widehat{N}$ is not within $\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{N\log(2/\alpha)}{2}}$ of $Np$, then you should be suspicious with confidence $100(1-\alpha)\%$.*

Equivalently, if you're interested in the frequency $\widehat{p} := \widehat{N}/N$ of item $x$ instead, then you have the following rule (obtained by dividing through the previous rule by $N$)

> *If $\widehat{p}$ is not within $\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{\log(2/\alpha)}{2N}}$ of $p$, then you should be suspicious with confidence $100(1-\alpha)\%$.*

This gives you a **nonasymptotic** $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval of width $\sqrt{\dfrac{2\log(2/\alpha)}{N}}$ for $p$. And it's not possible to do better than this (without further assumptions)...

## Extreme case: $p$ is too close to $0$ or $1$

Note that in our above analysis, the width of the confidence intervals don't depend on $p$, i.e are independent of the hypothesis being tested! Thus, the analysis gives us a uniformly blurred view of the situation. In case $\min(p, 1-p)$ is too small, we can run into trouble...

To fix the underlying issue, we resort to a generalization of Hoeffding's inequality. Viz

> **Bernett's inequality.** *Let $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ be iid random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\le \sigma^2$. Let $\overline{X}_N := (1/N)\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ be the empirical mean. Then, with probability at least $1-\alpha$ it holds that*
>   $$
> |\overline{X}_N - \mu| \le \sigma \sqrt{\frac{2\log(2/\alpha)}{N}}  + \frac{\log(2/\alpha)}{3N}.
> $$

In our case, we have

- $X_i = B_i$, Bernoulli distributed.
- $\overline{X}_N = \widehat{p}$.
- $\mathbb E [X_1] = \mu=p$, and we can take $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)$.

Given a tolerance level $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, let
$$
t_{N,\alpha}:=\sqrt{p(1-p)} \sqrt{\frac{2\log(2/\alpha)}{N}} + \frac{\log(2/\alpha)}{3N}.
$$
Then you have the following empirical frequency $\widehat{p}$

> *If $\widehat{p}$ is not within $\pm t_{N,\alpha}$ of $p$, then you should be suspicious with confidence $100(1-\alpha)\%$.*

Analogously, we have the following rule for the empirical count $\widehat{N}$

> *If $\widehat{N}$ is not within $\pm Nt_{N,\alpha}$ of $Np$, then you should be suspicious with confidence $100(1-\alpha)\%$.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, enough of it makes sense to me to be useful. I’m not sure what counts as too small here, but intuitively it seems to me that it should depend on p(x). For the data I’m working with probabilities ranges from 5% down to about 10,000th of that. N can range from 100 to 100,000. Don’t have enough maths ability to understand the linked document unfortunately.

Comment: OK, no pb. Unfortunately, I don't have as much free time as I would like to. I will find and write down the details regarding the extreme cases...

Comment: @neofight78 OK, as promised I've added a careful treatment of the extreme cases (i.e when $p$ is very close to $0$ or $1$). Don't forget to "Accept" the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a thorough and complete answer. I really appreciate it!

Comment: FYI Follow up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644371/determine-significance-of-deviation-from-expected-probability